# Drawing Polygon with multiple points

Tags: vb.net, drawing

I am trying to draw polygon from a string entered by user:
e.g. (0 0),(10 10),(20 20),(0 0)....n

Parsed the string as under:

```
Dim I As Integer, A0 As String, A1 As String(), X1 As Double, Y1 As Double, X2 As Double, Y2 As Double
    Dim MyChar() As Char = {"(", ")"}

    For I = 1 To sites.Length - 1 Step 1

        A0 = sites(I - 1)                 
        A0 = A0.TrimStart(MyChar)
        A0 = A0.TrimEnd(MyChar)
        A1 = A0.Split(" ")
        X1 = Val(A1(0))
        Y1 = Val(A1(1))

        A0 = sites(I)
        A0 = A0.TrimStart(MyChar)
        A0 = A0.TrimEnd(MyChar)
        A1 = A0.Split(" ")
        X2 = Val(A1(0))
        Y2 = Val(A1(1))
```

Now I want to draw line from x1,y1 and x2,y2 in each iteration so it complete the polygon
Next
I am unable to draw lines. Please help in using drawline method/draw polygon method that takes parameters from array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use @Jens solution and here is an another example of how to draw lines between a sequence of points using the simple draw line method. this approach assumes that the points are entered in an ordered sequence and not at random, otherwise, you will get lines crossing one another. You should consider enhancing your original parsing approach by creating a function that returns a point and not repeat the parsing code.

```
'settings for drawing 
        Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
        Dim blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 3)

        'assume the user will enter points as (x,y) pair
        'and each pair will go into a separate array cell
        Dim sites() As String = {"(0,0)", "(0,300)", "(250,300)", "(250,0)"}

        Dim I As Integer

        'Get the x,y coordinates of the point from the input string
        'You should turn this to a function that returns a point later
        Dim A0 As String, A1 As String(), X1 As Double, Y1 As Double, X2 As Double, Y2 As Double
        Dim MyChar() As Char = {"(", ")"}

        A0 = sites(0)
        A0 = A0.TrimStart(MyChar)
        A0 = A0.TrimEnd(MyChar)
        A1 = A0.Split(",")
        X1 = Val(A1(0))
        Y1 = Val(A1(1))
        point1 = New Point(X1, Y1)

        For I = 1 To sites.Length - 1 Step 1
            A0 = sites(I)
            A0 = A0.TrimStart(MyChar)
            A0 = A0.TrimEnd(MyChar)
            A1 = A0.Split(",")
            X2 = Val(A1(0))
            Y2 = Val(A1(1))
            point2 = New Point(X2, Y2)
            'draw line between points p1,p2
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point1, point2)
            'change the start point. Assumes that the points are in order
            point1 = New Point(X2, Y2)

        Next I
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use GDI+ for this. First you need something to draw on. You can draw directly on controls, or you can draw onto a bitmap which I'll show you here.
In order to use the points the user entered you should convert them into Drawing.Point objects. For example

```
Dim P1 as New Point(X1, Y1)
```

Say you have 3 points you can then use the Graphics.DrawPolygon method to draw the polygon. For this you need to create a new Graphics object. First you create the bitmap. You should determine the minimum and maximum X/Y values from the points in order to size the bitmap. Let's say you did this and stored the values in MinX, MaxX, MinY, MaxY variables. Create the bitmap by:

```
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(MaxX-MinX, MaxY-MinY)
```

Then create the graphics object (that provides the drawing functions)

```
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
```

Create an array of Point that contains all the points you create earlier from userinput. Let's say you have three points P1, P2, P3:

```
Dim Points() as Point = {P1, P2, P3}
```

Then use your graphics Object to draw the polygon.

```
g.DrawPolygon(Pens.Black, Points)
```

Since g is unmanaged you need to Dispose of it or you create a memory leak.

```
g.Dispose
```

This applies also to the Bitmap (bmp) we created but you want to continue using this so don't dispose it here. Do it later when you don't need it anymore. You can for example show the bitmap in a picturebox now.

```
PictureBox1.Image = bmp
```

I think you can work with this and expand it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Module    : bsPolygonButton (User Control)
' DateTime  : 08/11/2003
' Author    : Drew (aka The Bad One)
' Purpose   : To provide a button control that takes the shape of a polygon
'             of almost any number of sides.
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Updates
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Explicit

Private Declare Function SetRect Lib "user32" (lpRect As RECT, ByVal X1 As Long, ByVal Y1 As Long, ByVal X2 As Long, ByVal Y2 As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreatePolygonRgn Lib "gdi32" (lpPoint As Any, ByVal nCount As Long, ByVal nPolyFillMode As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowRgn Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hRgn As Long, ByVal bRedraw As Boolean) As Long
Private Declare Function DeleteObject Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function FillRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hdc As Long, lpRect As RECT, ByVal hBrush As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function MoveToEx Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
Private Declare Function LineTo Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateSolidBrush Lib "gdi32" (ByVal crColor As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DrawText Lib "user32" Alias "DrawTextA" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal lpStr As String, ByVal nCount As Long, lpRect As RECT, ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function OffsetRect Lib "user32" (lpRect As RECT, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DrawFocusRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hdc As Long, lpRect As RECT) As Long
Private Declare Function TranslateColor Lib "olepro32.dll" Alias "OleTranslateColor" (ByVal clr As OLE_COLOR, ByVal palet As Long, col As Long) As Long

Private Type RECT
   Left As Long
   Top As Long
   Right As Long
   Bottom As Long
End Type

Private Type COORD
   X As Long
   Y As Long
End Type

Private Type POINTAPI
   X As Long
   Y As Long
End Type

Private Const WINDING = 2
Private Const DT_CALCRECT = &H400
Private Const DT_CENTER = &H1
Private Const DT_NOCLIP = &H100
Private Const DT_VCENTER = &H4

Private m_iSides As Integer

Const m_def_iSides = 6
'Default Property Values:
Const m_def_ShowFocus = True
Const m_def_CaptionColour = vbButtonText
Const m_def_ButtonColour = &HFC2FF
Const m_def_LightestColour = &H86E1FF
Const m_def_LightColour = &H57D6FF
Const m_def_DarkColour = &H99CC&
Const m_def_DarkestColour = &H769D&
Const m_def_iRotation = 90

'Property Variables:
Dim m_ShowFocus As Boolean
Dim m_CaptionColour As OLE_COLOR
Dim m_ButtonColour As OLE_COLOR
Dim m_Fount As Font
Dim m_LightestColour As OLE_COLOR
Dim m_LightColour As OLE_COLOR
Dim m_DarkColour As OLE_COLOR
Dim m_DarkestColour As OLE_COLOR
Dim m_Caption As String
Dim m_iRotation As Integer

'Event Declarations:
Event Click()
Event KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
Event KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
Event KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
Event DblClick()

Const Pi# = 3.1415927
Const CLR_INVALID = &HFFFF

Dim hRegion As Long
Dim booGotFocus As Boolean


'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : bsPolygonButton.Sides
' DateTime  : 08/11/2003
' Author    : Drew (aka The Bad One)
' Purpose   : Gets/sets the number of sides the button has.
' Assuming  : Number of sides is between 3 and 100, inclusive.
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Public Property Get Sides() As Integer
   Sides = m_iSides
End Property

Public Property Let Sides(ByVal iSides As Integer)

   If m_iSides < 3 Then
      m_iSides = 3
   ElseIf m_iSides > 100 Then
      m_iSides = 100
   End If

   m_iSides = iSides
   Call UserControl.PropertyChanged("Sides")
   DrawControl
End Property

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : bsPolygonButton.DrawControl
' DateTime  : 09/11/2003
' Author    : Drew (aka The Bad One)
' Purpose   : Draws the whole control (pressed if necessary).
' Assuming  : nothing
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Private Sub DrawControl(Optional booPressed As Boolean)
   Dim X(0 To 1) As Single, Y(0 To 1) As Single
   Dim rctControl As RECT, lpOld As POINTAPI
   Dim I As Integer, iCounter As Integer
   Dim hBrush As Long

   Dim PolyCoord(100) As COORD

   SetWindowRgn UserControl.hWnd, 0, True
   ScaleMode = vbPixels
   AutoRedraw = True

   ' Clear the control (button colour)
   ' -------------------------------------------------------------------
   SetRect rctControl, 0, 0, ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight
   hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(TranslateColour(m_ButtonColour))
   FillRect UserControl.hdc, rctControl, hBrush
   DeleteObject hBrush

   ' Remember, X coordinate = Sin(angle) * X radius + X centre, and
   '           Y coordinate = Cos(angle) * Y radius + Y centre


   ' Draw text
   ' -------------------------------------------------------------------
   Set Font = m_Fount
   DrawText hdc, m_Caption, Len(m_Caption), rctControl, DT_CALCRECT
   If UserControl.Enabled Then
      ForeColor = TranslateColour(m_CaptionColour)
      OffsetRect rctControl, ScaleWidth / 2 - rctControl.Right / 2, _
         ScaleHeight / 2 - rctControl.Bottom / 2
      If booPressed Then
         OffsetRect rctControl, 1, 1
      End If
      DrawText hdc, m_Caption, Len(m_Caption), rctControl, DT_CENTER + DT_VCENTER + DT_NOCLIP
   Else
      ForeColor = TranslateColour(m_LightColour)
      OffsetRect rctControl, ScaleWidth / 2 - rctControl.Right / 2 + 1, _
         ScaleHeight / 2 - rctControl.Bottom / 2 + 1
      DrawText hdc, m_Caption, Len(m_Caption), rctControl, DT_CENTER + DT_VCENTER + DT_NOCLIP
      ForeColor = TranslateColour(m_DarkColour)
      OffsetRect rctControl, -1, -1
      DrawText hdc, m_Caption, Len(m_Caption), rctControl, DT_CENTER + DT_VCENTER + DT_NOCLIP
   End If

   ' Draw focus rectangle
   ' -------------------------------------------------------------------
   If booGotFocus And m_ShowFocus Then
      DrawFocusRect hdc, rctControl
   End If

   ' Draw the edges
   ' -------------------------------------------------------------------
   For I = 0 To 360 Step 360 / m_iSides
      X(0) = Sin(DegreesToRadians(I + m_iRotation)) * ((ScaleWidth - 1) / 2) + ((ScaleWidth - 1) / 2)
      Y(0) = Cos(DegreesToRadians(I + m_iRotation)) * ((ScaleHeight - 1) / 2) + ((ScaleHeight - 1) / 2)
      X(1) = Sin(DegreesToRadians(I + m_iRotation + 360 / m_iSides)) * ((ScaleWidth - 1) / 2) + ((ScaleWidth - 1) / 2)
      Y(1) = Cos(DegreesToRadians(I + m_iRotation + 360 / m_iSides)) * ((ScaleHeight - 1) / 2) + ((ScaleHeight - 1) / 2)

      ' first line
      DrawWidth = 2
      If booPressed Then
         ForeColor = TranslateColour(m_DarkestColour)
      Else
         If (ScaleHeight - (X(1) / ScaleWidth) * ScaleHeight <= Y(1)) Then
            ForeColor = TranslateColour(m_DarkColour)
         Else
            If ScaleHeight - (X(0) / ScaleWidth) * ScaleHeight <= Y(0) Then
               ForeColor = TranslateColour(m_DarkColour)
            Else
               ForeColor = TranslateColour(m_LightestColour)
            End If
         End If
      End If
      MoveToEx hdc, X(0), Y(0), lpOld
      LineTo hdc, X(1), Y(1)

      ' second line
      DrawWidth = 1
      If booPressed Then
         ForeColor = TranslateColour(m_DarkColour)
      Else
         If (ScaleHeight - (X(1) / ScaleWidth) * ScaleHeight <= Y(1)) Then
            ForeColor = TranslateColour(m_DarkestColour)
         Else
            If ScaleHeight - (X(0) / ScaleWidth) * ScaleHeight <= Y(0) Then
               ForeColor = TranslateColour(m_DarkestColour)
            Else
               ForeColor = TranslateColour(m_LightColour)
            End If
         End If
      End If
      MoveToEx hdc, X(0) + 1, Y(0) + 1, lpOld
      LineTo hdc, X(1) + 1, Y(1) + 1
   Next

   ' Create polygon region
   ' -------------------------------------------------------------------
   For I = 0 To 360 Step 360 / m_iSides
      PolyCoord(iCounter).X = Sin(DegreesToRadians(I + m_iRotation)) * ((ScaleWidth + 1) / 2) + ((ScaleWidth + 1) / 2)
      PolyCoord(iCounter).Y = Cos(DegreesToRadians(I + m_iRotation)) * ((ScaleHeight + 1) / 2) + ((ScaleHeight + 1) / 2)
      iCounter = iCounter + 1
   Next
   hRegion = CreatePolygonRgn(PolyCoord(0), m_iSides, WINDING)
   SetWindowRgn UserControl.hWnd, hRegion, True

   ' Because we've set AutoRedraw to True...
   Refresh
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_Click()
   RaiseEvent Click
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_DblClick()
   RaiseEvent DblClick
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_ExitFocus()
   booGotFocus = False
   DrawControl
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_GotFocus()
   booGotFocus = True
   DrawControl
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
   RaiseEvent KeyDown(KeyCode, Shift)
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
   RaiseEvent KeyPress(KeyAscii)
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
   RaiseEvent KeyUp(KeyCode, Shift)
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
   If Button = vbLeftButton Then
      DrawControl True '(PtInRegion(hRegion, X, Y) <> 0)
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
   If Button = vbLeftButton Then
      DrawControl True
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
   If Button = vbLeftButton Then
      DrawControl
   End If
End Sub

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : bsPolygonButton.UserControl_ReadProperties
' DateTime  : 08/11/2003
' Author    : Drew (aka The Bad One)
' Purpose   : Reads the stored values for the properties.
' Assuming  : nothing
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Private Sub UserControl_ReadProperties(PropBag As PropertyBag)
   m_iSides = PropBag.ReadProperty("Sides", m_def_iSides)
   m_iRotation = PropBag.ReadProperty("Rotation", m_def_iRotation)
   m_LightestColour = PropBag.ReadProperty("LightestColour", m_def_LightestColour)
   m_LightColour = PropBag.ReadProperty("LightColour", m_def_LightColour)
   m_DarkColour = PropBag.ReadProperty("DarkColour", m_def_DarkColour)
   m_DarkestColour = PropBag.ReadProperty("DarkestColour", m_def_DarkestColour)
   m_Caption = PropBag.ReadProperty("Caption", UserControl.Extender.Name)
   m_ButtonColour = PropBag.ReadProperty("ButtonColour", m_def_ButtonColour)
   Set m_Fount = PropBag.ReadProperty("Fount", Ambient.Font)
   m_CaptionColour = PropBag.ReadProperty("CaptionColour", m_def_CaptionColour)
   UserControl.Enabled = PropBag.ReadProperty("Enabled", True)
   m_ShowFocus = PropBag.ReadProperty("ShowFocus", m_def_ShowFocus)
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_Resize()
   DrawControl
End Sub

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : bsPolygonButton.Rotation
' DateTime  : 08/11/2003
' Author    : Drew (aka The Bad One)
' Purpose   : Allows the user to specify by how much the polygon is
'             "rotated".
' Assuming  : nothing
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Public Property Get Rotation() As Integer
   Rotation = m_iRotation
End Property

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : bsPolygonButton.Rotation
' DateTime  : 08/11/2003
' Author    : Drew (aka The Bad One)
' Purpose   : Allows the user to specify by how much the polygon is
'             "rotated".
' Assuming  : nothing
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Public Property Let Rotation(ByVal New_Rotation As Integer)
   New_Rotation = New_Rotation Mod 360
   If New_Rotation < 0 Then
      New_Rotation = 360 - New_Rotation
   End If
   m_iRotation = New_Rotation
   PropertyChanged "Rotation"
   DrawControl
End Property

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : bsPolygonButton.UserControl_InitProperties
' DateTime  : 08/11/2003
' Author    : Drew (aka The Bad One)
' Purpose   : Sets the default values for the properties.
' Assuming  : nothing
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Private Sub UserControl_InitProperties()
   m_iRotation = m_def_iRotation
   m_iSides = m_def_iSides
   m_LightestColour = m_def_LightestColour
   m_LightColour = m_def_LightColour
   m_DarkColour = m_def_DarkColour
   m_DarkestColour = m_def_DarkestColour
   m_Caption = Extender.Name
   m_ButtonColour = m_def_ButtonColour
   Set m_Fount = Ambient.Font
   m_CaptionColour = m_def_CaptionColour
   m_ShowFocus = m_def_ShowFocus
End Sub

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : bsPolygonButton.UserControl_Terminate
' DateTime  : 09/11/2003
' Author    : Drew (aka The Bad One)
' Purpose   : Removes the region from memory, before the control is destroyed.
' Assuming  : nothing
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Private Sub UserControl_Terminate()
   DeleteObject hRegion
End Sub

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : bsPolygonButton.UserControl_WriteProperties
' DateTime  : 08/11/2003
' Author    : Drew (aka The Bad One)
' Purpose   : "Saves" the properties for later use.
' Assuming  : nothing
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Private Sub UserControl_WriteProperties(PropBag As PropertyBag)
   Call PropBag.WriteProperty("Sides", m_iSides, m_def_iSides)
   Call PropBag.WriteProperty("Rotation", m_iRotation, m_def_iRotation)
   Call PropBag.WriteProperty("LightestColour", m_LightestColour, m_def_LightestColour)
   Call PropBag.WriteProperty("LightColour", m_LightColour, m_def_LightColour)
   Call PropBag.WriteProperty("DarkColour", m_DarkColour, m_def_DarkColour)
   Call PropBag.WriteProperty("DarkestColour", m_DarkestColour, m_def_DarkestColour)
   Call PropBag.WriteProperty("Caption", m_Caption, UserControl.Extender.Name)
   Call PropBag.WriteProperty("ButtonColour", m_ButtonColour, m_def_ButtonColour)
   Call PropBag.WriteProperty("Fount", m_Fount, Ambient.Font)
   Call PropBag.WriteProperty("CaptionColour", m_CaptionColour, m_def_CaptionColour)
   Call PropBag.WriteProperty("Enabled", UserControl.Enabled, True)
   Call PropBag.WriteProperty("ShowFocus", m_ShowFocus, m_def_ShowFocus)
End Sub

'WARNING! DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE FOLLOWING COMMENTED LINES!
'MemberInfo=10,0,0,0
Public Property Get LightestColour() As OLE_COLOR
   LightestColour = m_LightestColour
End Property

Public Property Let LightestColour(ByVal New_LightestColour As OLE_COLOR)
   m_LightestColour = New_LightestColour
   PropertyChanged "LightestColour"
   DrawControl
End Property

'WARNING! DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE FOLLOWING COMMENTED LINES!
'MemberInfo=10,0,0,0
Public Property Get LightColour() As OLE_COLOR
   LightColour = m_LightColour
End Property

Public Property Let LightColour(ByVal New_LightColour As OLE_COLOR)
   m_LightColour = New_LightColour
   PropertyChanged "LightColour"
   DrawControl
End Property

'WARNING! DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE FOLLOWING COMMENTED LINES!
'MemberInfo=10,0,0,0
Public Property Get DarkColour() As OLE_COLOR
   DarkColour = m_DarkColour
End Property

Public Property Let DarkColour(ByVal New_DarkColour As OLE_COLOR)
   m_DarkColour = New_DarkColour
   PropertyChanged "DarkColour"
   DrawControl
End Property

'WARNING! DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE FOLLOWING COMMENTED LINES!
'MemberInfo=10,0,0,0
Public Property Get DarkestColour() As OLE_COLOR
   DarkestColour = m_DarkestColour
End Property

Public Property Let DarkestColour(ByVal New_DarkestColour As OLE_COLOR)
   m_DarkestColour = New_DarkestColour
   PropertyChanged "DarkestColour"
   DrawControl
End Property

'WARNING! DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE FOLLOWING COMMENTED LINES!
'MemberInfo=13,0,0,usercontrol.extender.name
Public Property Get Caption() As String
   Caption = m_Caption
End Property

Public Property Let Caption(ByVal New_Caption As String)
   m_Caption = New_Caption
   PropertyChanged "Caption"
   DrawControl
End Property

'WARNING! DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE FOLLOWING COMMENTED LINES!
'MemberInfo=10,0,0,vbbuttonface
Public Property Get ButtonColour() As OLE_COLOR
   ButtonColour = m_ButtonColour
End Property

Public Property Let ButtonColour(ByVal New_ButtonColour As OLE_COLOR)
   m_ButtonColour = New_ButtonColour
   PropertyChanged "ButtonColour"
   DrawControl
End Property

'WARNING! DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE FOLLOWING COMMENTED LINES!
'MemberInfo=6,0,0,0
Public Property Get Fount() As Font
   Set Fount = m_Fount
End Property

Public Property Set Fount(ByVal New_Fount As Font)
   Set m_Fount = New_Fount
   PropertyChanged "Fount"
   DrawControl
End Property

'WARNING! DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE FOLLOWING COMMENTED LINES!
'MemberInfo=10,0,0,vbbuttontext
Public Property Get CaptionColour() As OLE_COLOR
   CaptionColour = m_CaptionColour
End Property

Public Property Let CaptionColour(ByVal New_CaptionColour As OLE_COLOR)
   m_CaptionColour = New_CaptionColour
   PropertyChanged "CaptionColour"
   DrawControl
End Property

'WARNING! DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE FOLLOWING COMMENTED LINES!
'MappingInfo=UserControl,UserControl,-1,Enabled
Public Property Get Enabled() As Boolean
   Enabled = UserControl.Enabled
End Property

Public Property Let Enabled(ByVal New_Enabled As Boolean)
   UserControl.Enabled() = New_Enabled
   PropertyChanged "Enabled"
   DrawControl
End Property

'WARNING! DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE FOLLOWING COMMENTED LINES!
'MemberInfo=0,0,0,True
Public Property Get ShowFocus() As Boolean
   ShowFocus = m_ShowFocus
End Property

Public Property Let ShowFocus(ByVal New_ShowFocus As Boolean)
   m_ShowFocus = New_ShowFocus
   PropertyChanged "ShowFocus"
End Property


'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : bsPolygonButton.ShowAbout
' DateTime  : 09/11/2003
' Author    : Drew (aka The Bad One)
' Purpose   : Shows the About screen.
' Assuming  : nothing
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
'Public Sub ShowAbout()
'  frmAbout.Show vbModal
'End Sub

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : modUseful.DegreesToRadians
' DateTime  : 08/11/2003
' Author    : Drew (aka The Bad One)
' Purpose   : Converts a value in degrees to radians, as used by Visual Basic.
' Assuming  : nothing
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
```

put the following in a user control and you can have any sided polygon

```
Function DegreesToRadians(ByVal sngAngle As Single) As Single
   DegreesToRadians = sngAngle * (Pi / 180)
End Function
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : TranslateColour
' DateTime  : 12/10/2003
' Author    : Drew (aka The Bad One)
' Purpose   : Used to convert Automation colours to a Windows (long) colour.
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Function TranslateColour(ByVal oClr As OLE_COLOR, Optional hPal As Long = 0) As Long
   If TranslateColor(oClr, hPal, TranslateColour) Then
       TranslateColour = CLR_INVALID
   End If
End Function
```